# "Static declaration of ‘memfd_create’ follows non-static declaration" Error while building Linux image using Yocto

Tags: static, yocto, imx6, angstrom-linux

I am building Linux Image using `Yocto`build system on `Ubuntu 18.04` host machine. I am following steps provided over [here](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/board-support-package/openembedded-(core)#Additional_Layers). I am building for `Colibri iMX6ULL` computer-on-module. However, my build has failed and it is showing errors given below

```
declaration of ‘memfd_create’ follows non-static declaration
|  static int memfd_create(const char *name, unsigned int flags)
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
| In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mman-linux.h:115:0,
|                  from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mman.h:45,
|                  from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/mman.h:41,
|                  from /home/abhiarora/iohertz/gateway_os/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.10.0-r0/qemu-2.10.0/include/sysemu/os-posix.h:29,
|                  from /home/abhiarora/iohertz/gateway_os/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.10.0-r0/qemu-2.10.0/include/qemu/osdep.h:104,
|                  from /home/abhiarora/iohertz/gateway_os/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.10.0-r0/qemu-2.10.0/util/memfd.c:28:
| /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mman-shared.h:46:5: note: previous declaration of ‘memfd_create’ was here
|  int memfd_create (const char *__name, unsigned int __flags) __THROW;
|      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
| /home/abhiarora/iohertz/gateway_os/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.10.0-r0/qemu-2.10.0/rules.mak:66: recipe for target 'util/memfd.o' failed
```

And this error:

```
| gcc  -c -I. -I../lib -I../../git/lib -isystem/home/abhiarora/iohertz/gateway_os/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/e2fsprogs-native/1.43.5-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -isystem/home/abhiarora/iohertz/gateway_os/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/e2fsprogs-native/1.43.5-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../../git/debugfs/../e2fsck -DDEBUGFS ../../git/debugfs/quota.c -o quota.o
| ../../git/debugfs/../misc/create_inode.c:406:18: error: conflicting types for ‘copy_file_range’
|  static errcode_t copy_file_range(ext2_filsys fs, int fd, ext2_file_t e2_file,
|                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| In file included from ../../git/debugfs/../misc/create_inode.c:19:0:
| /usr/include/unistd.h:1110:9: note: previous declaration of ‘copy_file_range’ was here
|  ssize_t copy_file_range (int __infd, __off64_t *__pinoff,
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| gcc  -c -I. -I../lib -I../../git/lib -isystem/home/abhiarora/iohertz/gateway_os/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/e2fsprogs-native/1.43.5-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -isystem/home/abhiarora/iohertz/gateway_os/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/e2fsprogs-native/1.43.5-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../../git/debugfs/../e2fsck -DDEBUGFS ../../git/debugfs/xattrs.c -o xattrs.o
| Makefile:422: recipe for target 'create_inode.o' failed
| make[2]: *** [create_inode.o] Error 1
| make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

The packages/tasks that were failed:

1. e2fsprogs_1.43.5
2. qemu_2.10.0

Can someone help me? I can't switch to ubuntu 16.04 but I think it should be working with my system as well.

Comment: Looks like this is glibc2.27 version issue. I am trying to install older versions to make things work.

Comment: Downgrading glibc in a Ubuntu installation is probably not a very good idea since glibc is used from almost every packages. This might end up in quite a dependency hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue at Toradex and is on the Roadmap, see issue [#36657](https://developer.toradex.com/software/linux/linux-software/release-details?view=all&issue=36657).

Fixes are already in the upstream layers, and we have updated our BSP repo. You can try this branch by using the LinuxImageV2.7-integration branch.